# ASP.NET horizontal menu with submenu appearing below, also horizontal

Tags: asp.net, menu, submenu, aspmenu

I've got a horizontal menu with UL/LI markup that I want to convert to an ASP:Menu in .net 3.5.

I'd like choices in the submenu to be rendered in a horizontal menu below the main menu when the main menu option is clicked. I also want to:

- indicate which menu option is chosen by highlighting/bolding both the main menu and submenu,
- check on rendering (or via some other mechanism) the role of the user to show only the proper menu options.

Comment: Wow. This is the first time I've heard of someone throwing away a css based ul/li menu in favor of using an asp:menu control.  It's almost always the other way around.

Comment: It's more a conflict of how to accomplish the same thing using CSS menus. I'd prefer to avoid the built-in controls when they aren't flexible and when they cause postbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS friendly adapters: http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/

These will allow you to keep the ul/li markup and give you the ability to highlight via css and control the rendering just like you would with a normal asp:Menu with the roles.